# C# Expose events from Excel vsto Addin for other addins

Tags: c#, excel, events, com, vsto

I want my excel vsto addin to expose some events for other addins. As I understood, RequestComAddInAutomationService can be used to allow others to call some code from my addin. To avoid referencing an addin from another addin, I declare interfaces in a separate library

```
//in some library
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IManager
{
    void DoSmth();
}

//in the excel addin

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public class Manager: IManager
{
    internal readonly static Manager Instance = new Manager();
    private Manager(){}
    public void DoSmth()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    protected override object RequestComAddInAutomationService()
    {
        return Manager.Instance;
    }
    //...
}
```

this allows me to call DoSmth method from different addins on the same instance of Manager class.

```
object name = "ManagerService";
return (IManager) application.COMAddIns.Item(ref name).Object;
```

I tried adding an event to that interface and implementing it:

```
//in some library
public delegate void MyDelegate(Worksheet worksheet, MyEventArgs e);
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Value{get;}
    public MyEventArgs(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}


[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IManager
{
    void DoSmth();
    event MyDelegate MyEvent;
}
```

But attemts to subscribe to this event

```
object name = "ManagerService";
var manager = (IManager) application.COMAddIns.Item(ref name).Object;
manager.MyEvent += (worksheet, args) => {
//...
};
```

causes `System.InvalidCastException` and `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` to be thrown (in the output window);
I failed to find any information about exposing events with RequestComAddInAutomationService. 
So what is the correct way to expose events with an interface from an excel addin for other addins.